# UI integration with Smart Contract in case of using JavaScript VM

Tags: remix, web3-providers, javascript-vm

Is it possible to integrate an UI with a smart sontract in case of using java script vm in remix ? or we have to use web3 provider ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could technically use remix in that fashion, but it would be very unreliable performance wise. Your best bet would be to use metamask as your web3 provider. It's a very easy to use addon that can be installed into any browser and will allow people to access your UI for your smart contract using metamask nodes as the web3 provider.

https://metamask.io/

https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md